# Sorting a large table from highest to lowest values

Tags: r

I have an extremely large contingency table (9000 * 9000), since I'm interested in the number of times a specific pair occurs in my original dataset. I want to format this in such a way that I have a new `data.frame` that contains the number of times the pair occurs, and which pair it is (the combination of `rowname` and `colname`).

```
d = data.frame(x1 = c(0,3,3,6),x2 = c(6,4,7,3))
> d
  x1 x2
1  0  6
2  3  4
3  0  7
4  6  3
```

I want the following:

```
  Num pair
1   7 x2-3
2   6 x2-1
3   6 x1-4
4   4 x2-2 
5   3 x2-4
6   3 x1-2
7   0 x1-3
8   0 x1-1
```

Is it possible to do this in a way that does not require a loop?

Comment: Your desired output is not exactly clear from your input...

Comment: Nor is it clear how your `d` relates to a 9000x9000 table...

Comment: Yeah, the opening paragraph has no apparent connection with the code. As far as the code goes, you could use `library(reshape2); melt(cbind(rownames(d),d))` for something very similar.

Comment: indeed, if we change the second `x2-3` to `x2-1` it would be (reversed, irksomely) coordinates

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you're after, but this mimics your output reasonably well:

```
out1<-unlist(d)
names(out1)<-paste0(rep(colnames(d),each=nrow(d)),"-",rownames(d))
out2<-sort(out1,decreasing=T)
result<-data.frame(Num=out2,pair=names(out2),row.names=1:length(out2))

> result
  Num pair
1   7 x2-3
2   6 x1-4
3   6 x2-1
4   4 x2-2
5   3 x1-2
6   3 x1-3
7   3 x2-4
8   0 x1-1
```

---

Also, if you'd really like the exact order you presented in the problem statement, line 3 should be changed to:

```
out2<-sort(out1[sort(names(out1),decreasing=T)],decreasing=T)
```

Comment: Or `names(d) <- paste0(names(d),"-"); stack(sort(unlist(d),decreasing=TRUE))`, though that defaces the columns of `d`.

Comment: Yes, I was also cringing at the thought of columns ending with `"-"`

Comment: @Frank OP could also avoid this hyphen mess by just adding something like `rownames(d)<-paste0("y",rownames(d))`

Answer (score 1):

```
result <- data.frame(Num = unlist(d),
                     pair = paste0(col(d,as.factor = T),'-',row(d)))
result[order(result$Num,decreasing = T), ]
```